# Multiple coupon codes

Tags: cognito-forms

I'd like to offer multiple coupon codes to track how our registrants come to us, but I don't want multiple coupon code fields on my form. Can I have multiple equations in just one field?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can set up multiple coupon codes in one calculation by adding another check in the 'if else' calculation found in our [3 ways to create discounts blog post](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/3-easy-ways-to-create-discounts-on-payment-forms).

You can start off with the simple calculation discount, in my example I have 3 fields.

1. The Choice field titled 'Choice' that will have 3 options that have an amount attached to each of them.
2. The Textbox field titled 'Coupon Code' that will collect the coupon code.
3. The Price field titled 'Discount' that will run the calculation bases on the other two fields.

The calculation that we start out with will check for just one coupon code and apply a 10% discount if its been typed in.

```
=CouponCode = "CODE1" ? -Choice_Amount*0.10 : 0
```

As it stands, when the coupon code 'CODE1' is typed in the user will get 10% off, but you can expand on this and add other codes to give the user 15% and 20% off as well.

```
=CouponCode = "CODE1" ? -Choice_Amount*0.10 : CouponCode = "CODE2" ? -Choice_Amount*0.15 : CouponCode = "CODE3" ? -Choice_Amount*0.20 : 0
```

Each new coupon code will start with 'CouponCode = "NewCode" ' You will then need to tell it what the new code should equal, this will be the percent that is provided as a discount.

I have set up a [Multiple Coupon Code Demo](https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/CognitoFormsTestAccount/MultipleCouponCodeDemo) with this calculation in action. You can view it and copy the template into your Organization to review the calculation and test out how it works.